# Does it make sense to apply dependency inversion if it requires instantiating a dependency with default values to update them later?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, solid-principles, dependency-inversion

In this example a Database gets a get_image method which returns an Image. To respect the DIP the example include all the necessary interfaces.

```
import abc


class ImageInterface(abc.ABC):
    """Represent and manipulate images"""


class ImageParserInterface(abc.ABC):
    """Image parser"""

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def decode(self, data: str) -> ImageInterface:
        """Parse string to Image"""


class DatabaseInterface(abc.ABC):
    """Communicate with a database"""

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_image(self, image_id: str) -> ImageInterface:
        """Get an image stored in the database from it's id"""


class ImageRGB(ImageInterface):
    """Represent and manipulate RGB images"""


class ImageParserMongoDBToRGB(ImageParserInterface):
    """Convert result from MongoDB query to ImageRGB"""

    def decode(self, data: str) -> ImageInterface:
        """Parse string to Image"""
        return ImageRGB()


class DatabaseMongoDB(DatabaseInterface):
    """Communicate with a MongoDB database"""

    def __init__(self, image_parser: ImageParserInterface):
        self._image_parser = image_parser

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def fetch_image_data(self, image_id: str) -> str:
        ...

    def get_image(self, image_id: str) -> ImageInterface:
        image_data = self.fetch_image_data(image_id)
        return self._image_parser.decode(image_data)
```

The Dependency Inversion Principle [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle):

- A1: High-level modules should not import anything from low-level modules
- A2: Both should depend on abstractions (e.g., interfaces).
- B1: Abstractions should not depend on details.
- B2: Details (concrete implementations) should depend on abstractions.

A1 and B1 are respected, since all interfaces depend only on interfaces. 
A2 and B2 are not, since ImageParserMongoDBToRGB depends on ImageRGB which is not an interface.

In this case would it make sense to initialize ImageParserMongoDBToRGB with an empty ImageRGB as below simply to respect the dependency inversion principle ?

```
class ImageParserMongoDBToRGB(ImageParserInterface):
    """Convert result from MongoDB query to ImageRGB"""

   def __init__(self, image: ImageInterface):
      self.image = image

    def decode(self, data: str) -> ImageInterface:
        """Parse string to Image"""
        self.image.data = image_data
        return self.image
```

Answer (score 1):

my guess is that you are confusing dependencies with data.
A dependency in your case is your MongoDB persistence layer. Actually, since you are serializing the image in a specific format, tied to your MongoDB, your `DatabaseMongoDB` class should take care of loading the data and mapping it to a class implementing `ImageInterface`.

Comment: Do you mean that the DIP should not be applied to data ? And that instances of ImageInterface should be considered as data here ?

The way I understand DIP is that no implementation or interface should be instantiated in another implementation or interface. Is this correct ?

Comment: you are loading an image from the DB, therefore that is your data. The fact that you're mapping it to something that uses a contract (the ImageInterface), doesn't make it a dependency.
Again, services are to be considered dependencies. And you are correct, those should not be instantiated. Data can, even if it implements an interface :)